# React Google OAuth 2.0: Some requested scopes were invalid

Tags: reactjs, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, jsx

I am trying to use Google OAuth 2.0 to sign in to my web application. I am requesting the following scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

When I try to authorize my app, I get the following error message:

Some requested scopes were invalid. {invalid=[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.go...
I have also enabled the scopes in the Google Cloud Console. However, I am still getting this error message.

```
const scope = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
].join(' ');

const params = {
    response_type: 'code',
    client_id: googleClientId,
    redirect_uri: `${apiBaseURL}/${redirectUri}`,
    prompt:'select_account',
    access_type:'offline',
    scope
};

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
window.location = `${googleAuthUrl}?${urlParams}`;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it with plus sign

```
{
  ..., 
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+openid+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
}
```

Scopes defines with string divided by **space character** or **plus sign**

Comment: Thanks I will try it, btw it worked iwth a space also